# Confidence box for coefficients of linear regression?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, linear-model, prediction-interval

I am learning linear regression and I am trying to create a visualisation. Say I want to estimate a power model $y=ax^b$ using linear regression. I take the logarithm to get

$$\ln(y)=\ln(a)+b\ln(x)$$
Now I can run linear regression on log log of the data. Say I run the regression and I get that
$$\hat{y}=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x$$.
I understand how to compute the confidence intervals for each $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ individually from well known formulas. However, I would like to figure out the confidence "box" for $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$. I assume this box is a little smaller than the cross products of individual confidence boxes for $\beta_0,\beta_1$ in general, but it may not be. To my understanding, my question is related to the confidence band. The confidence band gives us a "region" within which with 95% chance our true line lies. The prediction band is:
$$\hat{y}=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x \pm \sqrt{\text{Quadratic stuff}}$$
This is fine, but how do I now find the confidence bands for $ax^b$? My naive approach is to take the prediction band above, replace all $x$ with $\ln(x)$ and raise both sides to the power $e$. This of course will no longer be power functions, but will certainly resemble them. Are those the new prediction bands for the power model?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking for the _confidence_ interval for $\bar y$ are some given $x$? Or for the _prediction_ interval for $y$ given some $x$?

Comment: @AlexJ I would like the confidence "box" (2 dimensional interval), s.t, with probability of at least 95%, the true parameters of the regression lay in that box. I think that would correspond to confidence bands.

Comment: Edited, my apologies. I think it is indeed confidence bands.

Comment: This is only half a solution, because I don't have the knowledge off the top of my head. But $(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)$ should be (approximately) distributed as a 2-dimensional Gaussian with expectation $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (which you will get from your model fitting). You should be able to plot this in 2D. That's half of it. The half that's missing is getting the 95% confidence region (it will not be a square box, it will be some vaguely elliptical shape), which idk off the top of my head, sorry

Comment: I still find your question a bit unclear, btw. For example, the question appears to be about a 2D confidence region for $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$. But then you're asking about "but how do I now find the confidence bands for $ax^b$" which is related but different

Comment: @AlexJ I think it is my ignorance showing. I guess I would like to ultimately figure out two "extreme" lines. Between which, the true line lies with 95% certainty. Hence my convoluted question.

Comment: I _think_ you just want a 95% confidence interval on $y_i$ for various values of $x_i$, basically so you can plot the curve with confidence regions?

Comment: Essentially yes. But I would like these confidence intervals to be between the two lines (even If I over shoot a bit for some parts)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are two options. The first is to use the log-transformed formulation you are using. The second is to use a generalised linear model formulation. I think the second way is better, but I will illustrata both.

In both, we start with the power equation $y=ax^b$ that we're interesting in estimating for a dataset of $x$ and $y$ variables.

### Option 1 - log transform

This is the approach you propose in your question body.

Taking logarithms on both sides gives $\log y= \log a + b \log x$.

By using ordinary least squares, we are actually modelling the mean of the LOG: $E[\log y] = \log a + b \log x$. The parameter estimate $\hat\beta_0$ is estimating $\log a$, and $\hat\beta_1$ is estimating $b$. Note $(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)$ is a 2D Gaussian with variance-covariance matrix estimated during the modelling process.

If you want to get a confidence interval on $\log y$ (e.g. for plotting on a line chart), that's easy. For a sequence of $x$ values, use some standard formulae for variances:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{var}(\log y_i) &= \text{var}(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 \log x_i) \\
&= \text{var}(\hat\beta_0) + (\log x_i)^2 \text{var}(\hat\beta_1) + (2\times 1\times \log x_i)\text{cov}(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)
\end{aligned}
$$

You can get all of these values from the output of your model.

BUT, there is an issue here. Exponentiating $E[\log y]$, i.e. $\exp(E[\log y])$, doesn't return $y$. Which brings me to the second option...

### Option 2 - log-link GLM

Again we start with $y=ax^b$. Now we'll model instead $\log(E[y])=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \log x$. This can be fit with most statistical packages using a GLM with a log link. Again, $(\hat\gamma_0, \hat\gamma_1)$ is a (approximately) 2D Gaussian with variance-covariance matrix estimated during the modelling process.

Here's the benefit of this way. When we go to estimate the variance

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{var}(\log(E[y_i])) &= \text{var}(\hat\gamma_0 + \hat\gamma_1 \log x_i) \\
&= \text{var}(\hat\gamma_0) + (\log x_i)^2 \text{var}(\hat\gamma_1) + (2\times 1\times \log x_i)\text{cov}(\hat\gamma_0, \hat\gamma_1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now if we exponentiate both sides it's more useful.

- $\exp(\log(E[y]))=E[y]$, which is what we want
- We can calculate a confidence interval on $\log(E[y])$ in log-space, using the above equation. Let's call that interval $[L,U]$. Exponentiating that interval gives us an (asymmetric) confidence interval on $E[y]$

Here's some R code with an example

```
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(x, a, b) a * x^b
A <- 0.5 # set some parameter values
B <- 1.9

set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:50
)
df$y <- f(df$x, a = A, b = B) +
  rnorm(n = nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 20) # just adding some noise

ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))

mdl <- glm(data = df
           , formula = y ~ log(x)
           , family = gaussian(link = "log")
           , start = c(0.6, 2))
summary(mdl)

exp(coef(mdl)["(Intercept)"]) # approx = A
coef(mdl)["log(x)"] # approx = B

# predictions of log(E[y])
df[, c("pred_log", "se_log")] <- predict.glm(object = mdl
                                             , newdata = df
                                             , type = "link"
                                             , se.fit = TRUE)[c("fit", "se.fit")]
# pred and se are on log scale
df$pred_real <- exp(df$pred_log)
df$L_log <- df$pred_log - 1.96 * df$se_log
df$U_log <- df$pred_log + 1.96 * df$se_log
df$L_real <- exp(df$L_log)
df$U_real <- exp(df$U_log)

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + # raw data
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = L_real, ymax = U_real) # confidence bands
              , alpha = 0.2
              , fill = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = pred_real)) + # predicted curve
  geom_line(aes(x = x # actual curve
                , y = f(x = x, a = A, b = B))
            , colour = "green")
```

Black points: actual data. Shaded blue interval is confidence interval on the mean for various $x$. Black line is the fitted curve, green line is the true curve.

[image]